# nginx: delay sending proxy request through?

Tags: web-server, nginx

I'm set up nginx to proxy requests to a pool of web servers. I'd like nginx to limit the number of concurrent requests to each web server, by waiting to forward the request, so that a web server isn't overwhelmed. Is there a way to do this in nginx?

Answer (score 2):

[UpstreamFair module](http://nginx.localdomain.pl/wiki/UpstreamFair) can handle other load balancing modes besides round robin. For example: with the weight parameter you can tell nginx doesn't send more than weight requests to any single backend.